# how to edit the elements of a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

d={'sym':'A'}

leg = [d for i in range(2)]

for i in range(2):

```
leg[i]['sym'] = leg[i]['sym']+str(i)
```

print(leg)

outut: [{'sym': 'A01'}, {'sym': 'A01'}]

Expected output:  [{'sym': 'A0'}, {'sym': 'A1'}]

Comment: Use `leg = [d.copy() for i in range(2)]`

Comment: The expression `leg = [d for i in range(2)]` created a list with two _copies_ of `d` in a list that was assigned to `leg`.  This is identical to `[d] * 2` which the linked thread addresses.  Try instead `leg = [{'sym':'A'} for i in range(2)]` which is one of the solutions provided in the thread.

Comment: @metatoaster
In the actual case, d is quite lengthy. Is there any way to define d(the expression) separately?

Comment: You may instead use the alternative `d.copy()` or `deepcopy` as prescribed in one of the answers in the linked thread.